# type or namespace could not be found / Xamarin

Tags: xamarin.ios, mvvmcross

i tried the MVVMCross Tutorial over at https://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&list=PLR6WI6W1JdeYSXLbm58jwAKYT7RQR31-W&v=_DHDMNB_IeY&t=1563s. Android works very fine.

```
I'm currently at iOS and it does not work like in the video. It says: 
Error   8   The type or namespace name 'MvxMessage' could not be found (are you missing a using          directive or an assembly reference?)
```

so i can't to anything. Do you guys know what to do?

Edit: I use Xamarin.iOS Unified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The general advice seems to be *not* to use the unified projects yet.

See:

- [Could not install package MvvmCross.PortableSupport 3.2.1 at Visual Studio 2013 for PCL Profile 158](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26068750/could-not-install-package-mvvmcross-portablesupport-3-2-1-at-visual-studio-2013)
- http://blog.xamarin.com/is-the-ios-unified-api-for-me/ - "if you don’t need to utilize the App Extensions framework today, hold off on moving to our preview Unified API"

Comment: Thanks Stuart, i tried to create a new Portable Class Library and dechecked the Xamarin.iOS Unified API but "it will be automatically targeted because they support the same set of portable APIs: Xamarin.iOS (Classic), Xamarin.iOS Unified API."
I think i must edit the Target-Framework myself, hm?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26068750/could-not-install-package-mvvmcross-portablesupport-3-2-1-at-visual-studio-2013 - the accepted answer there has some solutions to these new files from some Xam installers