# New iOS MVVMCross project - which Nuget package and/or PCL targets?

Tags: ios, mono, xamarin, mvvmcross, portable-class-library

We are creating a new iOS project. I want to use the Universal API so pretty sure I need to switch to Xamarin Beta channel and pull the prerelease of MVVMCross.

However when I try and add the MVVMCross package to a fresh PCL I get

> Could not install package 'MvvmCross.PortableSupport 3.5.0-beta1'. You
>   are trying to install this package into a project that targets
>   'portable-net45+sl50+Xamarin.iOS10+MonoAndroid10+MonoTouch10', but the
>   package does not contain any assembly references or content files that
>   are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the
>   package author.

The error looks simple enough but those compatibility errors from NuGet are never as simple as they look

The PCL is targetting

- .NET 4.5
- Silverlight 5
- Xamarin Android
- Xamarin.iOS
- Xamarin.iOS (Classic)

Which targets do I need to change so I can add the correct MVVMCross to build Universal iOS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like Your challenge is supporting Silverlight 5 - `sl50`

All the other platforms you list will support *modern* PCL profiles like 78 and 259. However, Microsoft haven't built any `Silverlight` support for these profiles.

This dropping of the "older profiles" is why MvvmCross dropped the old WindowsPhone support - announced back in July 2013 http://slodge.blogspot.co.uk/2013/07/mvvmcross-wp7-tombstoned.html

Comment: I don't care for SL5 and have tried unticking it but I get the "The following will be automatically targeted" message so it configures it anyway. I have tried unticking everything other than .NET 4.5 and Xamarin.iOS and still get compat errors.

Comment: SL5 is your problem... Options: 1. Edit the targeted profile number yourself in the csproj file; 2. Look through the reference assembly folders to see what is installed in what profile on your PC; 3.tag your question with `xamarin` and `Portable-class-library` and hope one of the PCL gurus can assist you.

Comment: Retagged and hacking about with csproj now. Thanks Stuart

Comment: It would not let me simply change to Package 259. It kepy saying "Update required" against the project. I needed to also change the TargetFrameworkVersion. See this answer, http://stackoverflow.com/a/26127667/63286. Stuart it might be worth you editing your answer to mention the framework version to

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem you had. I managed to fix it without hacking csproj. I couldn't deselect Silverlight 5. I selected Windows 8 target and then I was able to deselect Silverlight 5.